# Remove Specific Word in a specific order from String with Regex

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I have to remove the words "in" (in) from a string such as "Company X in Source B in Chair F" such that the string after regex applied is Company X Source B Chair F.

I also need to remove the quotation marks, and I have solved that.

I have tried the following regex with no success:

```
let str = "Company X in Source B in Chair F"
str.replace(/['"\in]+/g, '') --> Compay X Source B Char F
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `\b` word boundaries to match the whole word. Also make sure you use the result of `replace` - it returns a new string:

```js
let str = "Company X in Source B in Chair F";
const res = str.replace(/\bin\b/g, "").replace(/  /g, " ");
console.log(res);
```

There's a second `replace` above due to the spaces. If you want to avoid that:

```js
let str = "Company X in Source B in Chair F";
const res = str.replace(/ in /g, " ");
console.log(res);
```

And if you need to replace quotation marks as well, use the regex OR operator `|`:

```
/(?:\bin\b)|"|'/g
```

Comment: They also say they need to remove quotes, and aren't doing it quite right if they are trying to include that in the same regex, so \bin\b|"|' should work instead of using the brackets they had.

Comment: Oops, missed that @FredMan.

Comment: Thank you for the assist! Works like a charm.

Comment: No problem @dyno, always glad to help.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need anything fancy for this, you can just use `/in/g`:

```js
let str = "Company X in Source B in Chair F"
console.log(str.replace(/in/g, ''));
```

However, you'll probably want to consider adding the word boundary `\b`, as `/\bin\b/g`:

```js
let str = "Company X in Source B in Chair F"
console.log(str.replace(/\bin\b/g, ''));
```